# Android - How to change text color in TextInputLayout (Material Components)?

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components

I need to change color in TextInputLayout text, without changing primary color. I only want to change the color of the text typed in by the user, not the hint. I can't find any attribute to do that... what I tried is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        <!-- Color definitions -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/secondaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/secondaryLightColor</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/secondaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/secondaryColor</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondaryTextColor</item>

        <item name="textInputStyle">@style/inputStyle</item>
    </style>
```

where the `@style/inputStyle` is:

```
    <style name="inputStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/secondaryTextColor</item> 
    </style>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I noticed that if i change the `colorPrimary` the text color chamges, but as I said, I can't change it. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are applying the color to the wrong component. `InputTexts` in Material are composed of two different components:`TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText`.

In this [Anatomy and Key Properties section of the Material Text Input Documentation](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#anatomy-and-key-properties) you can read the following note:

> **Note**: All the attributes on the tables below should be set on the `TextInputLayout`, with the exception of the input text attributes (which should be set on the `TextInputEditText`).

That means that depending on the `TextInput` part you want to style you will have to extend a different layout:

`TextInputLayout`: `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.*`

`TextInputEditText`: `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.*`

In the theme definition, to specify the style to apply to the `TextInputLayout`'s you use `textInputStyle`, and to specify the `TextInputEditText`'s style you use `editTextStyle`.

In your case, the text color is one of the `TextInputEditText` styles, and not `TextInputLayout`. So replace:

```xml
<item name="textInputStyle">@style/inputStyle</item>
```

with

```xml
<item name="editTextStyle">@style/editTextStyle</item>
```

And

```xml
<style name="inputStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/secondaryTextColor</item> 
</style>
```

with

```xml
<style name="editTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/secondaryTextColor</item> 
</style>
```

This will effectively change the text color of the input text.

**Update** I just realised you had already defined `colorPrimaryText` in the Theme.

Theme's `colorPrimaryText` is what prevails for the color of the text in the `TextInput`,so you either change that, or if you can't because affects other places, you override it... but it's not easy. You have to use `materialThemeOverlay`.

So first, use both `textInputStyle` and `editTextStyle` and instead of `android:textColor` in the Theme definition, and specify this in both of them:

```xml
<item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/myOverridingOverlay</item>
```

And finally, define your overlay, without a parent:

```xml
<style name="myOverridingOverlay" parent="">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#123456</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a `TextInputEditText` widget inside of `TextInputLayout` and in that, you can set `textColor` attribute as per normal.

Comment: Didn't work... I guess I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what. I also noticed that `colorButtonNormal` doesn't change button colore, so I think I'm definifely missing something

Comment: Please share your XML file.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the input text color via the edit text's **`android:textColor`** attribute in the edittext:

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     ..>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:textColor="#FF11AA"
            ../>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Otherwise since the text color of the `TextInputEditText` is currently based on **`android:textColorPrimary`** color you can also override it also using:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:theme="@style/customEdit"
            ../>
```

with:

```
  <style name="customEdit">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

Or you can define a custom style for the `TextInputLayout`:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/custom"
        ..>
```

with:

```
  <style name="custom" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/MyTextInputEditText_filledBox_custom_color</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTextInputEditText_filledBox_custom_color" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been almost 2 years now but I faced the same issue and looked for an answer the way I came up with is by just adding,

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/yourColor</item>
```

to your app's themes.xml (style). That'll do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/yourcolor</item>
```

EDIT for Corn on the Cob in comments

```
<style name="Theme.yourStyleName" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.TextInputEditText">
  
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/black</item>
   

</style>
```

colorOnSurface will chage the color of the text inside the edittext.

In Your Layout.xml

```
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:theme="@style/Theme.yourStyleName"
                    android:layout_height="48dp" />
```

Comment: hi, please could you provide an explanation for future readers?

Answer (score -1):

Just add this code inside the <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

android:textColorHint="yourcolor"    <- this is the code to add

> 

This will give color to it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This doesn't seem to answer the question which was specifically about the text color, *not the hint color*.